# Fetch 100 rows from child entity for each element from IN clause

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jdbc, one-to-many, hibernate-mapping

Parent to child Relation: OneToMany

```
Parent - table
+-----+---------+
|id   |   name  |
+-----+---------+
| 1   |  name1  |
| 2   |  name2  |
| 3   |  name3  |
+---------------+

child1 - table 
+--+---------+------+
|id|parent_id|name  |
+--+---------+------+
| 1|   1     |  qwe |
| 2|   1     |  asd | 
| 3|   1     |  dsf |
| 4|   2     |  xzc |
+--+---------+------+
```

Tables: company(Parent) and employee(Child). I want to fetch 100 recently joined employees for all given companies with the company's details.

```
SELECT c.*, e.* 
FROM company c 
JOIN (
    SELECT * 
    FROM employee 
    WHERE company_id IN(2,3,4,5) 
    ORDER BY joined_at DESC LIMIT 100
) e on e.company_id = c.id where c.id in (2,3,4,5)
```

The above query returns a total of only 100 employees, but I want 100 employees for each company provided in `IN` clause.

Comment: And the question is?

Comment: @Andronicus I have updated the question.

Comment: Make it 3 employees from each company, and see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

You can use Pageable that can fetch the child entities knowing the parent.
Note that this query will return a paginated result of Child.

```
 /**
  * Find Child entities knowing the Parent.
  */
  @Query("select child from Parent p inner join p.childs child where p = :parent")
  public Page<Child> findBy(@Param("parent") Parent parent, Pageable pageable);
```

And you can use it like this :

```
Page<Child> findBy = repo.findBy(parent, new PageRequest(page, size));
```

Comment: I want parent's details also along with child's details.